# Type declaration in tuple unpacking

Tags: ocaml

Given a type:

```
type coords = int * int
```

The following works:

```
# let c : coords = 3, 4;;
val c : coords = (3, 4)
```

I would also like to be able to do:

```
# let (x, y) : coords = 3, 4;;
  let (x, y) : coords = 3, 4;;
Error: Syntax error
```

But it complains about a syntax error on `:`. Is this syntactically possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax `let x : t = …` is the no-argument case of the more general syntax

```
let f a1 … an : t = …
```

where `t` is the return type of the function `f`. The identifier `f` has to be just an identifier, you can't have a pattern there. You can also write something like

```
let (x, y) = …
```

Here `(x, y)` is a pattern. Type annotations can appear in patterns, but they must be surrounded by parentheses (like in expressions), so you need to write

```
let ((x, y) : coords) = …
```

Note that this annotation is useless except for some cosmetic report messages; `x` and `y` still have the type `int`, and `(x, y)` has the type `int * int` anyway. If you don't want coordinates to be the same type as integers, you need to introduce a constructor:

```
type coords = Coords of int * int
let xy = Coords (3, 4)
```

If you do that, an individual coordinate is still an integer, but a pair of coordinates is a constructed object that has its own type. To get at the value of one coordinate, the constructor must be included in the pattern matching:

```
let longitude (c : coords) = match c with Coords (x, y) -> x
```

Comment: You can also have `let longitude (Coords (x, _)) = x` -- the let-syntax allows "unfailing patterns".

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
let x : t = ...
```

means that you are, in most cases needlessly, telling the compiler that the type of the name ***x*** is ***t*** (or maybe you just want to add this type information for readability purposes). In your example:

```
let (x,y) : coords =
```

you have to ask yourself: what is the name whose type is ***coords***? Clearly you define no such name, the type of *x* is *int* and so is the type of *y*. There's no name with type *coords* on the left side. If you already have a coords value, you can split it up as below:

```
# type coords = int*int ;;
type coords = int * int
# let c:coords = 3,4 ;;
val c : coords = (3, 4)
# let x,y = c;;
val x : int = 3
val y : int = 4
```

In the above example on the line

```
let  c: coords = 3,4 ;;
```

you are actually letting the compiler that the name c should be assigned a coords type (otherwise int*int will be used as the type).